# Is a 404 response reasonable for a search service?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, http-status-code-404

In a web context, suppose I have a server-side search which is accessed via JavaScript (AJAX). If I search for a word like "chewy dragees", and the server side search is successfully called, but it cannot find a search result for the term "chewy dragees", is it reasonable for the server to return a 404 HTTP status code? Or should the 404 code only be used for the case of the server side search itself not being found?

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between the resource identified by the URL not existing, and it existing but not finding anything. I wouldn't use 404 for the latter case, no, I'd use a 200 and return the (empty) result.

Comment: Is there a technical reason to not use 404 here?

Comment: Self-answer: the [HTTP RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) specifies "The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI". So 404 is specific to not finding the Request URI itself.

Comment: @ChewyDragees: Yeah. Of course, if you implement a REST API, the question gets trickier. Does it make sense to return a 404 if you format your query like this? `http://example.com/search/chewy+dragees` To me, still, no, but it's at least more open to interpretation... :-)

Answer (score 1):

yeah, use 404 if the search service itself is not found - as '0' results is still a valid 'find' ( status 200 )